# when trying to read a file in databricks i get IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I am new in databricks, so I am trying to read .text file using spark.read.option as shown in the code snippet bellow :

```
df = None

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
for category in filtred_file_list:
  data_files = os.listdir('HMP_Dataset/'+category)
  for data_file in data_files:
    print(data_file)
    temp_df = spark.read.option('header', 'falso').option('delimiter'," ").csv("HMP_Dataset/"+category+"/"+data_file, schema=scheme)
    temp_df =temp_df.withColumn('class', lit(category))
    temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('source', lit(data_file))
    if df is None : 
        df = temp_df
    else :
        df.union(temp_df)
```

unfortunately i get the error below:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: HMP_Dataset/Brush_teeth/Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-f1.txt
```

Comment: data_files = os.listdir('/HMP_Dataset/'+category)

Answer (score 2):

Use "file:/databricks/driver/HMP_Dataset/" + category bla bla

instead of "HMP_Dataset/"+category+"/ etc...